# Can rsync work in write-only mode?

Tags: rsync, backup

We are configuring a Linux backup server at work that all of our other servers (also mostly Linux) will send backups to. The backups are hundreds of gigabytes in size, and have thousands of files, 99% of which don't change from day to day.

Normally, this is the perfect use case for rsync. Unfortunately, one of our requirements is that the backup server be write-only, so that servers can upload backups to it, but nothing can have access to those backups remotely, in case any of those servers get compromised. We currently have vsftpd setup to work in write-only mode, which works great, except for the fact that hundreds of gigabytes of data needs to go through the network every night.

As far as I know, because rsync does a comparison of the remote files with local files, it needs both read and write access on the remote server.

My question is this: is there any mode that rsync can run in where the backup server can reveal the checksums, and filenames of the files on it, but not the actual data? That means it would still be a write-only server, but we could do differential backups instead of full backups.

Comment: I doubt it. But why don't you just do it the Linux way, and create a separate user on the backup server for each server-client? Then each server-client only has access to its own backups.

Comment: So the clients may not even read their own backup?

Comment: use btrfs and transfer only the differences between snapshots. https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Manpage/btrfs-send

Comment: Note, rsync only reads file contents when it has found a mismatch in the size or timestamp etc (depending on your options), and wants to optimise the network copy of the changes. You can stop this with `--whole-file` and the whole new file will be copied over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are just trying to reduce network traffic, but don't mind wasting local disk space, a novel solution is to "mirror" the backup locally, then use rsync's batch mode to send the differences to the remote.

Loosely, you would do local backups with

```
rsync --write-batch=foo -a /src/dir/ /localcopy/dir/
```

This creates a file `foo` with all the changes to make, and a one-line script in `foo.sh` to run on the remote to interpret the contents. Copy both to the remote, then run the script on the remote:

```
scp foo foo.sh remote:
ssh remote ./foo.sh /dir/
```

or if you prefer:

```
ssh remote rsync --read-batch=- -a /dir/ <foo
```

You might also look at [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/) for rsync which encrypts the data on the remote, so you would also need to steal the encryption key to exploit the data.

Answer (score 2):

There is a write only mode in rsync version [2.6.3](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/NEWS#2.6.3) or later (for implementation details see commit [7a92ded39a](https://git.samba.org/rsync.git/?p=rsync.git;a=commit;h=7a92ded39a3f278dc31323ccddb680748db5b7ab)). It behaves as you described in your question.

Configuration in [rsyncd.conf](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsyncd.conf.5):

> **write only**
>
> This parameter determines whether clients will be able to download
> files or not. If "write only" is true then any attempted downloads
> will fail. If "write only" is false then downloads will be possible
> if file permissions on the daemon side allow them. The default is for
> this parameter to be disabled.

```
[module]
path = /some/path
read only = no
write only = yes
...
```

If you try to receive files from a write only repo you will get an error:

```
$ rsync rsync_host::module .
ERROR: module is write only
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(804) [sender=3.1.2]
```